# NET8 Blazor and Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-8.0, serilog-aspnetcore

I'm creating a new Blazor Application with NET8. In the main project, the "server" project that contains the Blazor Client, I tried to add `Serilog` adding at the top of the *Program.cs*

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/liu_api-.txt", 
                              rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();

builder.Services.AddSerilog();
```

after installing from the NuGet those packages:

- Serilog.AspNetCore (also the 7.0.1-dev-00320)
- Serilog.Extensions.Hosting (7.0.0)
- Serilog.Sinks.Console (5.0.0-dev-00923)

Unfortunately, the `Serilog.AspNetCore` is not recognized.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATYbu.png]

Is it possible right now to use `Serilog` with NET8?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘not recognised’?

Comment: Definitely using it with .NET 8 here, may be a local package repository issue?

Comment: I'm still having this issue. @NicholasBlumhardt what version are you using?